# render failed in sharepoint 2007 filter in a calculated filed

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I am trying to filter by url in a list, but I get this error,

```
<!---RENDER FAILED-->
```

The following is the code

```
  http://cgydv14690:8001/sites/dev/FCEE%20Documents/Forms/All%20Documents.aspx?FilterName=ColourClasification&FilterMultiValue=Green;Red
```

If I apply a filter this way `FilterField1=ColourClasification&FilterValue1=Green` it works perfectly. It is just failing when I try to use it to filter for two or more criteria.

Could this be because it is a calculated column?

This is the problem I need to address, there is a colum called colour clasification this is a calculated colum, based in the formula four values will be shown, green, red, yellow and not in formula, I need to filter for all values except for "not in formula", and I think there is no != to use in the url.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The error is RENDER FAILED

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Sharepoint, so I had to figure out another way to accomplish this.